# Как перестроить блок в другой ряд

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-grid

Есть следующая задача, карточки расположены по две в ряд на десктопе и каждая имеет равную ширину, которая равна 50%, при клике на карточку добавляется класс active и эта карточка начинает занимать всю ширину экрана.

Проблема, если мы совершаем клик на левую карточку, то все происходит как нужно, карточка, которая находится справа идет вниз. Но, если мы кликнем на правую карточку, то карточка, которая находится слева останется на своем же месте и справа от нее будет пустое пространство. (Пример на картинке)

Как сделать так, чтобы карточка уходила вниз. Прибегать к использованию jquery не нужно, не пойму как достучаться до предыдущего элемента

```css
.items
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.item
{
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 43%;
  margin: 30px;
}

.item.active
{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item active"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Сколько активных карточек может быть одновременно?

Comment: Тогда очередность меняться будет. То есть чтобы первый элемент вниз уходил под второй?

Comment: @Евгений Мусеев можете пожалуйста сбросить codepan пример, для дальнейшего решения вопроса

Comment: Не понимаю, почему вы используете такой костыль с `margin` и `flex-basis`. Есть же `gap`.